# Django says pillow is not installed yet it is installed to latest version

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library, imagefield

I used an imagefield and when I made migrations it showed this error

```
(venv) C:\Users\Eli Heist\PycharmProjects\Vector Final>python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
vector.Project.pic: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

I ran the command and It was satisfied already

```
(venv) C:\Users\Eli Heist\PycharmProjects\Vector Final>python -m pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\eli heist\pycharmprojects\vector final\venv\lib\site-packages (7.2.0)
```

What could be the problem
Even django and pip are up to date

Comment: Make sure you are using the right interpreter for the project

Answer (score -1):

I think I will be able to answer this.
My system info are follows:

- Windows 10
- Django version 3.2
- Python version 3.7

I found on the Pillow documentation that the tested version of Pillow  is 7.1.0
You can read [here.](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#other-platforms)
for this, you need to launch cmd or anaconda prompt and type

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow==7.1.0
```

if your python version is different you can check the link and install the right one .